# Get value of an cell with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the text/value of my cell.

My table looks somewhat like this:

```
    <table id="tablef" class="table table-striped">
    </table>
```

And i insert rows via `insertRow(-1)`

```
    var table = document.getElementById("tablev");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    var button = row.insertCell(1);
    cell.innerHTML = "\<center\>" + name + "\<\/center\>";
    cell.id = "cell" + i;
    var cellbutton = "\<input id='button" + i + "' type='button'value=\'Entfernen\' class='btn btn-link' >";
    button.innerHTML = "\<center\>" + cellbutton + "\<\/center\>";
```

I do know the cell id, but i cant figure out how to get the data that is in the cell

i tried : `var cellValue = $(cellID).innerHTML;` but that just gives me "undefined"

Comment: try `$(cellID).html()`

Comment: the proper jQuery function would be `.html()`, `$()` refers to a jQuery object whereas `.innerHTML` is a plain js function

Comment: You're inserting items after the DOM loads, I'm not sure in pure javascript but with jQuery, you will need to use a `.on()` to get the info from there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is not part of the jQuery API, you need to use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead, to get text and tags, or 
[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) if you only want the text.

Try `$(cellID).html()` instead.

`innerHTML` works on the native Element which you could access via `$(cellID)[0]`

Comment: Instead of [0], you should do everything in the jQuery way. Try $(cellID).get(0).innerHTML. Of course, better would be to just $(cellID).html()

Comment: Well, i tried that aswell but that wont work neither, still get "undefined"

Comment: If it doesn't work you're probably not triggering that code at the right moment, the element with id of cellID would need to be available on the document.

Comment: @GiIlesC am getting data form sql via ajax and then create rows and cells with that data first cell = text second cell = button, however after all entries are created i bind an click function to the button on each row wich then tries to alert the text from cell one. all of that happens after document.ready